# Apple Magic mouse problem

Tags: mouse

I am having one problem with the Magic mouse; after 3-4 hours of continuos use, the Magic mouse automatically loses connection with my Macbook pro.

Do you have any idea? Why is it happening?
Is it a defect? Should I go for replacement?

Comment: It could just as easily be a problem with your Mac. Do you have any other bluetooth devices? Do they experience the same problems?

Comment: It happens to me too.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the pram? http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues you're describing very common, along with many reasons why; fortunately there are some workarounds that might help.

The first reason you could be losing connectivity is because many macs have improper antenna configurations for the Airport and Bluetooth modules. This causes the signal to either be extremely weak, or just flaky in general. It get's progressively worse if the batteries on your mouse are starting to run low - much worse! Another reason is the Mouse itself having an aluminum battery cover that shields the bluetooth inside of it from having a decent connection.

**[Here are a few ways that might help resolve some of the issues]**

For starters take off the bottom battery cover and see if you have better responsiveness and connectivity. It works for me, although I have one of the macs with a backward antenna configs, so without doing that I basically have no connectivity. Another surprising fix is to download BTT (Better Touch Tool). I was very skepitcal about a third-party app helping remedy the situation, although I must admit that it helped tremendously. I'm not sure what mechanism the developer used to revive my mouse, but he's helped countless thousands I'm sure. If those two work-arounds don't do anything the last thing you can try is to re-wire your bluetooth antennna to hopefully make things work again.

The Magic Mouse has been plagued with these issues from day one, and besides getting another mouse that does the same exact thing there's not much else you can do. Oddly enough, the replacement that I got actually squeeks like mouse, and is worse than it's predecessor, which I'm currently wondering how to troubleshoot. Take a look at the article I've linked below; they might have a few other fixes that I might not have covered.

Link: [The Not So Magic Mouse](http://www.macworld.com/article/143702/2009/11/magicmouse.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is way too late to help the poster, but it might help others who look. I've found that my mouse has a tendency to lose connectivity. Even a simple tap against the edge of a mousepad or any hard object like my keyboard will knock it out when the mouse is feeling touchy. It can be especially bad if the batteries are weak. The fix is simple though.

Clean the contacts on the batteries, as well as the mouse itself. Some rubbing alcohol on a cotton Q-tip seems to do the trick, and no more mouse problems for at least 6 months.

Comment: Best hint ever. Just figured this out by myself and my ancient magic mouse has come to new life!

Answer (score 1):

Battery connection problem. It's a design fault imo. Try wrapping a paper around the batteries like he describes [here](http://macs.about.com/od/tipstricks/qt/Fix-Magic-Mouse-Disconnects.htm).

Two approaches:

- Place a piece of paper on top of the batteries, roughly centered. Tuck any excess paper around the edge of the batteries. Close the hatch.
- Place a small piece of alu foil on the negative terminal on the batteries.

The first wedges the batteries more sturdly in place and the second adds more area for the contacts.